# is there any option to limit the password reset using b2c custom policy in azure ad b2c?( like 2 times in hour)

Tags: .net, azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Current my reset password policy working fine.
now, I want to limit user to change their passwords again and again in a day (like 2 times in a day day or 2 times in an hour).
Can i handle this using b2c custom policy?

I'm not sure how can i get lastpassword changed date and time to handle in custom policy.
I know graphAPi resturns lastpassword changed date.

Comment: The simplest implementation would be to have an API back with Redis Cache. When a user resets their password you pop the attempt in Redis with an expiry of 1 day, 2 hours, whatever your case needs to be. You can handle this in custom policies but you'd need to have extension attributes for the user and handle all the logic in claims transformations. But really, it seems like a lot of effort for something the user should be allowed to do... It's their account, it's their security.